# How to maintain helm repository in gitlab

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, kubernetes-helm

I have a helm chart and I want to add it to my gitlab repository. But when I run:

```
helm repo add repo_name url
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: looks like "https://gitlab.<domain>.com/group/infra/repo/helm/charts/" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 3: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

Linter shows it is a valid chart.

Here is `index.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
entries:
  helloworld:
  - apiVersion: v2
    appVersion: 1.0.0
    created: "2021-06-28T14:05:53.974207+01:00"
    description: This Helm chart will be used to create hello world 
    digest: f290432f0280fe3f66b126c28a0bb21263d64fd8f73a16808ac2070b874619e7
    name: helloworld
    type: application
    urls:
    - https://gitlab.<domain>.com/group/infra/repo/helm/charts/helloworld-0.1.0.tgz
    version: 0.1.0
generated: "2021-06-28T14:05:53.973549+01:00"
```

Not sure what is missing here.

Comment: `helm` repo and `git` repo are different things.

Comment: exactly. what you actually want is to host a chartmuseum. which is basically a web-server hosting the files in a well-defined structure. check https://github.com/helm/chartmuseum for further information about hosting your own chart museum

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to use the helm chart that is hosted on the gitlab. Unfortunately, it won't work as you want it to. As [Lei Yang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1518100/lei-yang) mentioned well in the comment:

> `helm` repo and `git` repo are different things.

In the official documentation of Helm, you can find [The Chart Repository Guide](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/chart_repository/#create-a-chart-repository).
You can find it also a guide [how to create a chart repository](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/chart_repository/#create-a-chart-repository):

> A *chart repository* is an HTTP server that houses an `index.yaml` file and optionally some packaged charts. When you're ready to share your charts, the preferred way to do so is by uploading them to a chart repository.

Here you can find section, how to properly [host chart repos](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/chart_repository/#hosting-chart-repositories). There are several ways to do this - for example you can use a Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket, Amazon S3 bucket, GitHub Pages, or even create your own web server.

You can also use the [ChartMuseum](https://chartmuseum.com/docs/#using-with-local-filesystem-storage) server to host a chart repository from a local file system.

> ChartMuseum is an open-source Helm Chart Repository server written in Go (Golang), with support for cloud storage backends, including [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/), [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/), [Microsoft Azure Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/blobs/), [Alibaba Cloud OSS Storage](https://www.alibabacloud.com/product/oss), [Openstack Object Storage](https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/object-store/), [Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Object Storage](https://cloud.oracle.com/storage), [Baidu Cloud BOS Storage](https://cloud.baidu.com/product/bos.html), [Tencent Cloud Object Storage](https://intl.cloud.tencent.com/product/cos), [DigitalOcean Spaces](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/spaces/), [Minio](https://min.io/), and [etcd](https://etcd.io/).

Alternatively it could be also possible to [host helm charts in JFrog](https://jfrog.com/blog/host-your-helm-chart-in-chartcenter-directly-from-source/).

Answer (score 0):

You can host your own Public Helm repository on git.I have done it on Github and the process is very easy and straightforward.

You can follow this link
https://medium.com/@mattiaperi/create-a-public-helm-chart-repository-with-github-pages-49b180dbb417

You will have to package the chart and create an index.yaml file.You will also have to host your repository branch as Github pages.

I am not sure if gitlab also supports this but worth a shot.